How to use asyncio gather with sqlalchemy session in FastAPI and the workaround
I am trying to make an asynchronous call using asyncio gather to call multiple database query. I am getting error
sqlalchemy.exc.IllegalStateChangeError: Method 'close()' can't be called here; method '_connection_for_bind()' is already in progress and this would cause an unexpected state change to <SessionTransactionState.CLOSED: 5> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)

Based on this github https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9312
Its not possible to share the same session and doing asyncio.gather(func(session), func2(session)
Is there any solution that will make us able to do some db queries simultaneously?
Code:
async def handler(
    app_db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session_app),
):

# some other codes

        conversation_task = get_one_app(
            app_db,
            query=text("SELECT data_schema FROM conversations WHERE id = :conversation_id"),
            params={"conversation_id": conversation_id},
        )
        messages_task = get_all_app(
            app_db,
            query=text("""
                SELECT id, role, content FROM raw_messages WHERE conversation_id = :conversation_id
                ORDER BY created_at ASC, id ASC
            """),
            params={"conversation_id": conversation_id},
        )

        conversation, messages_result = await asyncio.gather(conversation_task, messages_task)

#rest of the code

database config
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("APP_DB_URL")

engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession
)

async def get_async_session():
     async with AsyncSessionLocal() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()


The only way I see is to use different sessions for each request.
In FastAPI you can use use_cache=False to get two sessions:
async def handler(
    app_db_sess_1: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session_app, use_cache=False),
    app_db_sess_2: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session_app, use_cache=False),
):


good point. The problem is, If I didnt know the exact number of sessions needed how will I come up with that?

Basically, I didnt know if my base thinking is correct or not, because coming from NodeJS background where it has things like Promise.all(func1(), func2()). So I thought asyncio.gather is quite similar to that.

You can pass sessionmaker to your endpoint (using dependency) and create as many sessions as you need dynamically. But I would re-think the architecture of your system to avoid parallel DB requests.
